# Codeigniter, how to pass COUNT result too my view

Tags: codeigniter, count

i have problem with passing data from model to my view. In Database i have Project with a few tasks  i need to COUNT it. My problem is: How to pass the results to the view with foreach.
(echo $this->db->count_all_results();   in MODEL show good results)

---

1. Project 1: 5 tasks
2. Project 2: 10 tasks
3. Project 3: 1 task

---

MODEL:

```
function wyswietl($arrayid){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( id_zadania ) AS zlicz
FROM projekty_zadania
WHERE id =$arrayid");
return $query->result();
```

---

CONTROLLER

```
function WszystkieProjekty(){
$data['moje'] = $this->Todo_model->wyswietlWszystkieProjekty();
 $arrayid = array();
   foreach( $data['moje'] as $row ){
   $row->id;
   $aaa = $row->id;
   $arrayid[] = $this->Todo_model->wyswietl($aaa);
    }
 $data['tabid'] = $arrayid;
 $this->load->view('Projekty.html', $data);
}
```

MODEL:

```
function wyswietlWszystkieProjekty(){

$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM todo");


 return $query->result();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing back to your controller a result set, so all you need to do is iterate over the result set, generating actual rows. It's not too hard, and you've got the right idea.

You have:

```
function wyswietl($arrayid){
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT( id_zadania ) AS zlicz
FROM projekty_zadania
WHERE id =$arrayid");
return $query->result();
```

As your model function that is supposed to return the count, right? Easiest way to do this is right from the model to keep your controller from having to do the legwork. When you run the count function in mysql, you'll only get back one row in your case, so using num_rows() isn't going to help because this query will always generate 1 row.

```
function wyswietl($arrayid){
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT COUNT(id_zadania) AS zlicz
        FROM projekty_zadania
        WHERE id =$arrayid");
    $rs = $query->result();
    return $rs[0]['COUNT(id_zaedania)'];
}
```

Comment: What should I do now, when i have COUNT result and want to see it in my view ( please show me this foreach ) :(

Comment: Now you're just getting demanding. The code I gave you above will return the actual count values. What you do with that value is up to you. The $arrayid variable inside your existing foreach loop will already be populated, each index, with the count, given the above function.

Comment: Thanks for help : SOLUTION IS:
IN MODEL JUST : $rs = $query->result();                IN VIEW : <?php foreach( $tabid as $row){echo $row['0']->zlicz; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

In your query, you have counted the data, so i think you can get the total data in the model from $query->rows()->zlics. And in the controller, just pass it to the view like usual

`$data['moje'] = $this->Todo_model->wyswietlWszystkieProjekty(); $this->load->view('Projekty.html', $data);`

Comment: He hasn't shown the code for model function wyswietlWszystkieProjekty() so you can't guarantee its return value. Additionally, he's using a COUNT query, which will only ever return one row in his context.

Comment: ah my bad, i mean he can actually return the count from $query->rows()->zlicz. i've edited my answer

Comment: What should I do now, when i have COUNT result and want to see it in my view ( please show this foreach ) :(

Comment: like i said before, you dont need to foreach in controller, because your model can return the count. change `return $query->result();` to return `$query->rows()->zlicz`, and you have your count

Comment: but in my view i dont know whant should i do :(
now i have : <?php foreach( $tabid as $row){   echo $row->zlicz; }  ?>, but is't wrong ;/